# how to read files from multiple folders in python

Tags: python, file, pandas, dataframe, directory

my folder organization looks like below. Type 1 and Type 2 folders contains same files but I want to only read the files from 'type 2' folder. Is there any simple way to do that?

I have used this code but not able to read:

```
for file in os.listdir('Type 2'):
    print file
```

[image: folder organization]

your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIUC you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) in folders `Type 2`, use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
files = glob.glob('main/**/Type 2/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: i got this error while reading.. glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

Comment: try remove it, solution is untested yet.

Comment: yes that might be the problems, now I am using 2.7.0 , but when I remove recursive it works perfectly :).